# XPath | create expression that finds a keyword in attributes - case-insensitiv

Tags: xml, xpath, translate, case-insensitive, contain

I have XML files with only some nodes. Anyhow the nodes have lots of attributes.
I am querying for attributes containing a specific keyword.

```
String expression = "/posts/row[@PostTypeId='1' and @*[contains(.,'Security')]]";
```

This is working fine, but only finding the exact match with a capital 'S'.
I want to have users provide the keyword and it is not in my hands whether they use only lower case. What I am trying to do is to use

```
//posts/row[translate(@*, ‘ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ’, ‘abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz’)]
```

to make everything lower case on XML side as well as the keyword and combine both attempts into one expression.

This is my attempt, but not working

```
String expression = "/posts/row[@*[contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '" + keyword + "')]]";
```

Can someone help me with that please? Am I totally wrong in my attempt?

Thanks in advance,
Bodo

---

It seems I could sort this out meanwhile with the following

```
String expression = "/posts/row[@PostTypeId='1' and @*[contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '" + keyword + "')]]";
```

I don't know what makes it working now, so anyone who can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

You're very close, but you mentioned translating the keyword to lower case but never do it. You will have to apply `translate` twice. I added some whitespace for better readability, you can but everything in one line again (and replace `$keyword` by the string concatenation you used, of course):

```
/posts/row[
  @PostTypeId='1' and @*[
    contains(
      translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
      translate($keyword, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    )
  ]
]
```

Make sure not to forget any non-ascii-characters like German umlauts or other accents! It might get annoying to implement such keywords. XPath 2.0 knows `lower-case(...)` which supports unicode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right about the keyword. I forgot to mention that I have done this before checking for similarity using the Java String method.